# Forcing Python to run in 64 mode from a NSTask subprocess

Tags: macos, cocoa, python-2.7, 64-bit, nstask

What is a method that forces python to run in 64 mode from a NSTask?

**Update: As per Ned's suggestion I tried referencing Python2.7 directly with objective c and that worked. Changed @"/usr/bin/python" to @"/usr/bin/python2.7". The new code is at the bottom of the question.**

I have a 64 bit system. When run from terminal python runs in 64 bit.
When I run a plain shell from a NSTask running /usr/bin/uname -m it returns x86_64.

I've tried using arch but the shell running python is still in 32 bit mode.

Example method

```
-(void) runPython64BitScriptViaArchWithPath:(NSString*)path {

    NSTask* task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    task.launchPath = @"/usr/bin/arch" ;
    task.arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-x86_64", @"/usr/bin/python", path, nil];

    [task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]] ;

    NSPipe *stdOutPipe = nil;
    stdOutPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput:stdOutPipe];

    NSPipe* stdErrPipe = nil;
    stdErrPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardError: stdErrPipe];

    NSLog(@"%@", [task arguments]) ;

    [task launch] ;

    NSData* data = [[stdOutPipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];

    [task waitUntilExit];

    NSInteger exitCode = task.terminationStatus;

    if (exitCode != 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error!");
        NSData *error = [[stdErrPipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile] ;
        NSLog(@"Exit code : %ld", (long)exitCode) ;
        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: error.bytes length:error.length encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        [result release];
    } else {
        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: data.bytes length:data.length encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
        NSLog(@"%@",result) ;
        [result release];
    }
    [task release] ;

}
```

an example python script that works if run from terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'social_shields.settings'

try:
    import hosts.models
    shield = hosts.models.Shield.objects.all()[0]
    shield.active = True
    shield.save()
except Exception as exception:
    import struct
    print 'Bits : %s' % ( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))
    print exception
```

example log

```
2013-07-04 16:10:31.600 socialshield[88688:303] onShieldDown
2013-07-04 16:10:31.607 socialshield[88688:303] x86_64
2013-07-04 16:10:31.607 socialshield[88688:303] (
    "-x86_64",
    "/usr/bin/python",
    "/source/social_shields/social_shields/shield_down.py"
)
2013-07-04 16:10:31.933 socialshield[88688:303] Bits : 32
Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

new code that works after applying Ned's suggestion :-)

```
-(void) runPython64BitScriptViaArchWithPath:(NSString*)path {

    NSTask* task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    task.launchPath = @"/usr/bin/arch" ;
    task.arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-x86_64", @"/usr/bin/python2.7", path, nil];

    [task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]] ;

    NSPipe *stdOutPipe = nil;
    stdOutPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput:stdOutPipe];

    NSPipe* stdErrPipe = nil;
    stdErrPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardError: stdErrPipe];

    NSLog(@"%@", [task arguments]) ;

    [task launch] ;

    NSData* data = [[stdOutPipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];

    [task waitUntilExit];

    NSInteger exitCode = task.terminationStatus;

    if (exitCode != 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error!");
        NSData *error = [[stdErrPipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile] ;
        NSLog(@"Exit code : %ld", (long)exitCode) ;
        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: error.bytes length:error.length encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        [result release];
    } else {
        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: data.bytes length:data.length encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
        NSLog(@"%@",result) ;
        [result release];
    }
    [task release] ;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have verified that `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so` is 64-bit and that you are really using the same Python in both cases.  On OS X 10.6 and later systems, `/usr/bin/python` is actually a wrapper executable that determines which version of Python and which architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) to run; see `man 1 python` for details.  Try executing `/usr/bin/python2.7` directly.  That should default to 64-bit.  You can also check whether Python is running in 32- or 64-bit mode by using this [documented test](http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.architecture):

```
import sys; print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)
```

Comment: Thanks Ned. The python versions _are_ different. That is the problem. From terminal it runs in 64 bit. From NSTask it runs in 32 bit mode. /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so is 64-bit. The code runs fine from terminal. Referencing 2.7 directly makes no difference on my machine. file /usr/bin/python2.7 returns /usr/bin/python2.7: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/python2.7 (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/python2.7 (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386

Comment: file /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64

Comment: Referencing 2.7 directly within the app worked Ned. Many thanks :-)